# data is not updating after performing action in angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am try to build my own custom data grid, it's working,
problem is after performing any actions like delete data is not updated

**my.component.html**

```
<grid [data] = "data" [columns]="columns"
  (actionChanged) = "onChangeAction($event)"> </grid>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
onChangeAction (actionData) {
    console.log(actionData, 'action change data in main component')
    if (actionData.action === 'delete') {
          this.delete (actionData)
    }

    if (actionData.action === 'add') {
        this.add (actionData)
  }
  }
  delete (actionData) {
    console.log(actionData, 'delete function calll', this.data.length)
    const index: number = this.data.indexOf(actionData.rowData.name);
    if (index === -1) {
        this.data.splice(index, 1);
    };
    console.log(this.data.length, index)  
  }
  add (actionData) {
    console.log(actionData, 'add function calll')
  }
```

**  grid.ts**

```
 @Output() public actionChanged:  EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  public updateAction (row, action) {
    console.log(row, 'Row', action)
    let actionData = {
          rowData: row,
          action: action
        }
   this.actionChanged.emit(actionData);
 }
```

I am passing data to grid using @Input() getting data from grid @outPUt()

I am getting data from grid-to-my.component perfect, probelm is after performing delete action data is not updated to grid.

Please any one can help me. 
  Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you listen to changes by implementing a method ngOnChanges

Comment: yes , I tried onChanges, Docheck events, with that probelm solved 50%,  data is updatng after delete action , but after performing filter function data is not updated

Comment: ngOnChanges() in grid.ts will listen to changes if anything changed in the @Input() properties. In your main component, onChangeAction() update the value of data, only then ngOnChanges() will trigger, so instead of this.data.splice() do this.data = this.data.splice()

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a method to grid.ts

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  // changes holds the new data
  // so you could set
  // this.data = changes;
}
```

Comment: here what is (changes: SimpleChanges)